# A question about discrete measure.

Tags: real-analysis

I have just started to read measure theory from very initial level. The note I am following refers to an example:

Atom: If $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ is a measure space, an atom of $\mu$ is a subset $A$ of $\mathcal{X}$ such that

$(i)$ $\mu(A)>0$.
$(ii)$ if $B\subset A$, then either $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$ or $\mu(B)=0$.

The measure space $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ is called discrete, if

$$X=Z\sqcup \bigsqcup\limits_{n=0}^\infty A_n,$$

where $\mu(Z)=0$ and $\{A_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a collection of atoms.

*Now the note asks to prove the following*

*If $X$ is countable, then for any measure $\mu$, the space $(X,\mathcal{X}, \mu)$ is discrete.*

I have no idea, how to proceed! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $Z$? A set?

Comment: My appologies@Snoop. I have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use the convention $\bigcap\emptyset=X$. For $x\in X$, define:
$$A(x):=\bigcap\{A\in\mathcal X|x\in A\}$$

For any $y\in X\setminus A(x)$, there is $A_y\in\mathcal X$ such that $x\in A_y$ and $y\notin A_y$. Using the axiom of choice, this yields a map $X\setminus A(x)\to\mathcal X, y\mapsto A_y$. The following holds:
$$A(x)\subset\bigcap_{y\in X\setminus A(x)} A_y\subset\bigcap_{y\in X\setminus A(x)} X\setminus\{y\}=X\setminus\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus A(x)} \{y\}=X\setminus (X\setminus A(x))=A(x)$$
Since $X$ is countable, so is $X\setminus A(x)$. Therefore, $A(x)=\bigcap_{y\in X\setminus A(x)} A_y\in\mathcal X$.

If $A\subset A(x)$ is measurable and $x\in A$, then $A(x)\subset A$, if $x\notin A$, then $A(x)\subset A(x)\setminus A$. Therefore, the only measurable subsets of $A(x)$ are $\emptyset$ and $A(x)$. In particular, $A(x)$ is either a null set or an atom. Furthermore, for any $x,y\in X$, either $A(x)=A(y)$ or $A(x)\cap A(y)=\emptyset$.

Define the following set:
$$\mathcal A:=\{A(x)|x\in X\}$$
Since $A:X\to\mathcal A$ is surjective, $\mathcal A$ is countable. The following holds:
$$X=\bigsqcup\mathcal A=\underbrace{\bigsqcup\{A\in\mathcal A|\mu(A)=0\}}_{=:Z}\sqcup \bigsqcup\{A\in\mathcal A|A\text{ atom}\}$$

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. What is $A_y$? @jb78685

Comment: For fixed $x$, $A_y$ is a measurable set containing $x$ but not $y$.

Comment: What is the explanation behind the third line " For any $y\in X\setminus A(x)~\dots$"@jb78685

Comment: $A(x)$ is the intersection of all $A\in\mathcal X$ with $x\in A$. Thus, if $y\notin A(x)$, there must be some $A\in\mathcal X$ with $x\in A$ with the property that $y\notin A$. We choose one such $A$ and call it $A_y$.

Comment: Is the map well-defined@jb78685

Comment: It is, assuming the axiom of choice. It is the composition of a choice function with the map $X\setminus A(x)\to\mathcal P(\mathcal X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ definied by $y\mapsto\{A\in\mathcal X|x\in A,y\notin A\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124555/discussion-between-jb78685-and-pmun).

Comment: I had the same idea but I didnt see how to show that $A(x)$ was measurable, good job!

Comment: @jb78685 Can you please tell me the ideas that led you to develop this proof? I'm asking this question because in your proof the following equivalent relation in $X$ appears implicitly: given any $x,y\in X$, $x\sim y$ if, and only if, $(\forall E\in\mathcal{X})(x\in E\Leftrightarrow y\in E)$.

Comment: @rfloc The main idea is to decompose $X$ into countably many measurable sets that have no measurable subsets other than $\emptyset$ and themselves, i. e., they are supposed to be as small as possible without being empty. This result is achieved by taking the equivalence classes wrt the property of being indistinguishable. This construction is an adaptation of Kolmogorov quotients to measure theory.

Comment: @jb78685 Do you know of any book that explains about the adaptation of Kolmogorov quotients to measure theory? If you know, then please tell me the name of the book!